# Checkbox selected or unselected after submit

Tags: php

I'm trying to make some kind of calculator,is there a way, if the checkbox is selected to be selected after submit and calculated in the result, if it is not selected for the result to be 0 and be unchecked after submit ..?
This is code..Tnx

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <label>Cal 1</label><input class="w-100 mb-1" type="text" name="kw" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cal_1'])) {echo $_POST ['cal_1']; } ?>" />
    <br>
    <label>Cal 2</label><input class="w-100 mb-1" type="text" name="ccm" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cal_2'])) {echo $_POST ['cal_2']; } ?>" />
    <br>
    <label>Cal 3</label><input class="w-100 mb-1" type="text" name="god" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cal_3'])) {echo $_POST ['cal_3']; } ?>" />
    <br>
    <label>Cal 4</label><input class="w-100 mb-1" placeholder="example 2" type="text" name="cal_4" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cal_4'])) {echo $_POST ['cal_4']; } ?>" />
    <br>
    <label>Cal 5</label><input class="w-100 mb-1" placeholder="Cal 5" id="number" type="text" name="cal_5" value="40" />
    <br>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4.00" id="defaultCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
            This is checkbox
        </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <input class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="submit" id="result" name="calculator" value="Result">
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['calculator'])){
    $cal_1  = $_POST['cal_1'];
    $cal_2  = $_POST['cal_2']; 
    $cal_3  = $_POST['cal_3'];
    $cal_4  = $_POST['cal_4'];
    $cal_5  = $_POST['cal_5'];
    $sum = $cal_1+$cal_2+$cal_3+$cal_4+$cal_5;
    
if($cal_1 <= 22) {
    $cal_1 = 128.13;
}
    if($cal_2 < 1101)$cal_2 = 35.00;
if ($cal_3 < 2012 && $cal_2 < 1151) {
    $cal_3 = 15.00;
} 
if($cal_2 < 51 && $cal_4 == 1 || $cal_4 == 0) {
    $cal_4 = 8.00;
}
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<font size=5><center>Cal 1: ".$cal_1."</center>"; 
    echo "<font size=5><center>Cal 2: ".$cal_2."</center>"; 
    echo "<font size=5><center>Cal 3: ".$cal_3."</center>";
    echo "<font size=5><center>Cal 4: ".$cal_4."</center>";
    echo "<font size=5><center>Cal 5: ".$cal_5."</center>";
    echo "<font size=5><center>Result: ".$result = $sum=$cal_1+$cal_2+$cal_3+$cal_4+$cal_5;"</center>";
   }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: The checkbox doesn't have a name, also where would you use it in the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible.
in the checkbox area you need PHP, like:

```
<?php

if ($_POST["checkbox"] == "4.00")
 {
  echo "<input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='4.00' id='defaultCheck1' checked>";
 }
else
 {
  echo "<input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='4.00' id='defaultCheck1'>";  
 }

?>
```

in calculation you need another **IF**

:)

Comment: Works fine only have error if uncheked Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in, but I'll try to solve the problem myself.Tnx for help

Comment: You can also do if (isset($_POST[„checkbox”])

Comment: fixed with isset.Tnx